# Can't find ssl_crtd (Squid3?)

Tags: 12.04

Needed to prepare cert cache for SSL bumping.  What package is this in?  I'm using the 3.3.4-1~precise1~ppa1 version from ppa:dirk-computer42/c42-backport because of bug #1175049. but it doesn't appear to be in the main versin (squid3_3.1.19-1ubuntu3.12.04.2_amd64.deb) either (nor squid3-common).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [squid-cache wiki](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump?highlight=%28ssl_crtd%29), `ssl_crtd` has effectively been replaced by `security_file_certgen` which can be located at `/usr/lib/squid/security_file_cergen`

> That fake certificate comes either from the security_file_certgen helper (older Squid call it ssl_crtd) or is generated ad hoc by Squid.

Comment: This should be in the official documentation and/or update it in their git repo's default config.

Answer (score -1):

I am on Arch Linux, but I eventually found it in `/usr/lib/squid/ssl_crtd` after installing squid.